# log4net.ext.json version 1.2.10 - wrong assembly in nuget package?

Tags: json, log4net

I installed log4net.ext.json version 1.2.10, but could not get it working after following the first steps. When I looked at the assembly in the nuget package, the version is 1.2.13.29. Is the wrong assembly version in the nuget package?

I'm looking for a version that is compatible with log4net version 1.2.11.0.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a binding redirect?

Comment: Not yet. JSON for log4net 1.2.13 requires log4net 2.0.3 and above.
JSON for log4net 1.2.10 requires log4net 1.2.10 and above, which will work with the version we're using. 

I'm trying to verify that the assembly version in the 1.2.10 nuget package is correct with the author, who states the best way to contact is via stackoverflow.

Comment: FYI log4net 2.0.3 _is_ 1.2.13

Comment: Got it, thanks. The main reason for this question, other than getting the package author's attention, is that both nuget packages for log4net.ext.json (1.2.10 and 1.2.12) contain the same version of the log4net.ext.json assembly (1.2.13.29).

Comment: I simplified things by trying to get this working in a console application instead of the web application I was working with. The assembly version of  log4net.ext.json seems to be ok. The issue is that log4net changed its public key token between 1.2.10 and 1.2.11, so binding redirects will not work. Hope that helps anyone that comes across this issue.

Comment: Oh, the new key, of course: I should have remembered that.. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

nuget probably wouldn't have it, but there is a release on SF that refers to the old-key log4net https://sourceforge.net/projects/log4net-json/files/20140804/

My suggestion - update away if you can :o)

UPDATE: old key is now really "old" and sourceforge project has been migrated over to github so the old-key release is gone. I hope no-one is depending on that anymore now. If so, please move on :o)